# Axios.create and CORS

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

I am using axios for making a post request with data to an endpoint:

This works:

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.post('https://example.com/v1/login', {
  name: 'myuser',
  password: 'mypassword',
});
```

But this doesn't

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const apiBase = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://example.com/v1/",
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
  },
});

apiBase.post('login', {
  name: 'myuser',
  password: 'mypassword',
});
```

Which logs:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/v1/login' 
from origin 'http://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 
value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must 
not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 
'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the 
XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

And actually, no header `'Content-Type'` is added to this request.

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

---

EDIT: modified following comments

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const apiBase = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://example.com/v1/",
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
  },
});

apiBase.defaults.headers['Content-Type'] = 'pplication/json;charset=UTF-8';
apiBase.defaults.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://example.com';
apiBase.defaults.headers['Host'] = 'example.com';
apiBase.defaults.headers['Referer'] = 'example.com';
apiBase.defaults.headers['Accept-Encoding'] = 'gzip, deflate, br';

apiBase.post('login', {
  name: 'myuser',
  password: 'mypassword',
});
```

Which still returns

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/v1/login' 
from origin 'http://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response 
to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the 
wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The 
credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled 
by the withCredentials attribute.
```

Comment: I think 'application/json' is enough. How you tried just that?

Comment: headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting credentials or setting the content-type to JSON will trigger a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).

The requirements for a response to a preflight are stricter than for a non-preflighted request.

One of them is, as the error message says, that you can't use the wildcard. You have to specify the origin explicitly. You aren't doing that.

> And actually, no header 'Content-Type' is added to this request.

Naturally. The preflight didn't get permission to set it, so the request is never made.

Comment: Thanks @quentin: edited question, as still find same error, even when the header is actually added to the request

Comment: @EmilleC. — The error message says "header in the **response**", not request

Answer (score 0):

Axios, for whatever reason, doesn’t allow you to send data in a POST request in the form of a JSON object when withCredentials is set to true.  You’ll need to stringify your data before passing it along.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code :

-----> apiBase.defaults.headers['Content-Type'] = 'pplication/json;charset=UTF-8';
apiBase.defaults.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;charset=UTF-8';

Comment: a bit more visually clear code formatting can be used